# How to disable product edit fields based on admin role in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, adminhtml, user-roles

I need to create one admin account for seo editer. This user only edit seo fields in `Product edit form` and `category edit form`

Default magento 2 Only disable menus, not a fields, I enabled only Product menu for this user.

Now, this user allows to edit, add, and delete the product and category. I need to restrict only enable seo fields in `Product edit form` and `category edit form`

**reference:**

**Product Edit Form:**

[image]

**Category Edit Form:**

[image]

**What i did:**

**di.xml** in below path app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit" />
    </config>
```

Then Override the Product Edit Controller.

`Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit.php:`

```
    <?php
    /**
     *
     * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

    class Edit extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit
    {

        protected $_publicActions = ['edit'];
        protected $resultPageFactory;
        protected $logger;
        protected $authSession;
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context, $productBuilder,$resultPageFactory );
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->logger =$logger;
            $this->authSession = $authSession;
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $this->logger->addDebug("product Edit Controller");

            if ($this->authSession->getUser()->getAclRole() == 4) {
                ?>

                <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                    {
                        "*": {
                            "Vendor_Module/js/seo_field":{}
                        }
                    }
                </script>

                <?php
            }
            return parent::execute();
        }
    }
```

This is My Script:

**seo_field.js**  create following `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/seo_field.js`

```
 define([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';

        console.log("testing");

        $('input[name="product[attribute_set_id]"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('input[name="product[name]"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('input[name="product[sku]"]').prop('disabled', true);
    });
```

Then, Disable the product edit fields based on name, But Not worked for  me,  script is being called fine,

Suggest me, why these fields are not disabled and how to fix this.

Comment: However it's not an elegant solution, you can hide fields after checking user role in admin session by including a custom phtml in product edit page.

Comment: I can post the code if you want

Comment: @Neo Please post that code for reference

Comment: Did the code work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow following steps if you want to hide/disable your fields according to admin user.
First include a phtml to product edit page in `before.body.end`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::hideattribute.phtml" name="after"/> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now in this phtml check the user using role id and hide corresponding attributes using given css (js is tricky because the attributes are rendered using knockout js).

```
    <?php 
    $role_id = ; //user's role id
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $adminSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
     $current_adminuser =    $adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleId();
    if($role_id == $current_adminuser): ?>
        <style>
/*check data-index for your required attributes as it is unique and does not changes with each refresh*/
    [data-index = approved] {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes your works for me

Comment: Do I need to create new module for this or need to edit core modules? I need set enable switch to disable for specific admin user. Can you help me?

Comment: @RameshKR you can manage that by adding configuration fields by system.xml and getting values from there. If it is not clear ask a separate question.

Comment: thanks @VivekKumar My question link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214997/how-to-give-approval-for-product-in-admin-dashboard