# How to give approval for product in admin dashboard?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, adminhtml, product-attribute

I have two administrator with different roles. I need admin who has all permissions to approve products added by another admin with low priority.

Comment: did my answer help you solve your problem

Comment: Really useful..But I'm confused in which file to add the field  you shown below.

Comment: s sure but can't change input value to something using data-index

Comment: I did mention that product page is rendered using uicomponent and ko js so it is difficult to apply js

Comment: I asked separate question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215187/how-to-chnage-input-tags-value-dynamically-which-is-in-knockout-js

Comment: Can you answer for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to make a field to manage which user roles are shown , you can add a select field in system configuration as follows ;

```
<field id="vendor_role" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>User Roles</label><source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\System\Config\Source\Roles</source_model>
</field>
```

Now you have to make a source model for this select field as follows ;

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\System\Config\Source;

class Roles implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    protected $_options;
    protected $_rolesFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Authorization\Model\ResourceModel\Role\Grid\CollectionFactory $rolesFactory)
    {
        $this->_rolesFactory = $rolesFactory;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $result = [];
        $roleCollection = $this->_rolesFactory->create()->load();

        foreach ($roleCollection as $role) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $role->getId(), 'label' => $role->getRoleName()];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now in your catalog_product_edit.xml and catalog_product_new.xml  include a phtml in `before.body.end`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::hideattribute.phtml" name="after"/> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now in this phtml check the user using role id and hide corresponding attributes using given css (js is tricky because the attributes are rendered using knockout js).

```
    <?php 
    $role_id = ; //get user's role id from system configuration
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $adminSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
     $current_adminuser =    $adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleId();
    if($role_id == $current_adminuser): ?>
        <style>
/*check data-index for your required attributes as it is unique and does not changes with each refresh*/
    [data-index = approved] {
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @vivek In which file to add the field you shown in first section of code.

Comment: system.xml , I did not post the full code as system.xml would have been different for your module

Comment: Also, please mark the answer as accepted if your query is solved

Comment: sure I need to turn of the enable switch to off and give display none for specific role can you help me

Comment: still product enable option is shown not hidden. I followed the same. How to find data index?

Comment: you can easily find by inspecting the field you want to hide in developer console

Comment: beware that the field itself would not have data-index but its wrapper div which includes label etc too will have it.

Comment: s in inspect element I see only data-bind..no data-index. I need to change input tag's value = 1 and hide the input..I'm a beginner but will learn soon

Comment: How did you learn all these stuffs and where do I learn all these

Comment: data index is found in the wrapper div..I need the input tag's value changed to 1..can ichange this using your logic..this is what I need..I hope you'll help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73766/discussion-between-ramesh-kr-and-vivek-kumar).

Comment: I get this error due to system.xml file  Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line