# How to disable product edit per field based on admin role in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, adminhtml, user-roles

I have some differents users that will be use the admin, on this way, I need to create different rules to edit the products. On this way, I´ll create a rule that the user can edit just PRICES and STOCK, just this.
I was following this exemple: [How to disable product edit fields based on admin role in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195799/how-to-disable-product-edit-fields-based-on-admin-role-in-magento-2) , but I believe that I need to do more things.
Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

According to what you were following you can do this.

I am assuming you have created a user, role, and assigned a role to the user. And new user only have catalog->product menu access only.

Now create a custom module.

**[Vendor]/[Module]/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor]_[Module]',
    __DIR__
);
```

**[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor]_[Module]" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[Vendor]_[Module]::hideattribute.phtml" name="after"/> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/templates/hideattribute.phtml**

```
<?php
    $role_id = 3; //user's role id for example I have used "3"
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $adminSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
    $current_adminuser =    $adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleId();
?>
<?php if($role_id == $current_adminuser): ?>
    <style>
[data-index = status],[data-index = attribute_set_id],[data-index = attribute_set_id],[data-index = name],[data-index = sku],[data-index = tax_class_id],[data-index = container_weight],[data-index = container_category_ids],[data-index = visibility],[data-index = container_news_from_date],[data-index = country_of_manufacture],[data-index = activity] {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

now you have to keep adding [data-index="indexName"] where indexName is what you will find in inspect at product edit page. For example `<div class="admin__field admin__field-small _required" data-bind="css: $data.additionalClasses, attr: {'data-index': index}, visible: visible" data-index="sku">`

Above thing in css and user's role id that two thing you will have to do mainly.